# Python 3.5 - Error-list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

Function to return an integer from a list with the maximum divisors. When I run my program, the following error is returned:

Error in evaluating function:
IndexError at line 22 (for i in range (1,input_list[3]+1):)
list index out of range

Please help.
My program is:

```
input_list= [8, 12, 18, 6]
def find_integer_with_most_divisors(input_list):
aCount=0
bCount=0
cCount=0
dCount=0
for i in range (1,input_list[0]+1):        
    a = input_list[0]
    if a%i==0:
        aCount+=1

for i in range (1,input_list[1]+1):
    b = input_list[1]       
    if b%i==0:
        bCount+=1

for i in range (1,input_list[2]+1):
    c = input_list[2]       
    if c%i==0:
        cCount+=1

for i in range (1,input_list[3]+1):
    d = input_list[3]       
    if d%i==0:
        dCount+=1

divisorsCount=[aCount,bCount,cCount,dCount]
maxIndex=divisorsCount.index(max(divisorsCount))
return input_list.pop(maxIndex)
print(find_integer_with_most_divisors(input_list))
```

Comment: It's working fine on my system.

Comment: @Anmol, thanks for trying.

Comment: After restoring identenation of the function definition, which obviously was in place when you ran it, I also run it without an error in Python 3.